# How to use the selected value in ComboBox to the SQL query?

Tags: c#, database, winforms

When I choose a value in ComboBox. How can I use them to query SQL??

I tried

```
private void cmb1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string select = this.cmb1.GetItemText(this.cmb1.SelectedItem);
   cm1 = new SqlCommand("select VS from DATABASE where ROUND=select", con);
   ap = new SqlDataAdapter(cm1);
   ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
   ap.Fill(ds, "DATABASE");
   cmb2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; 
   cmb2.DisplayMember = "VS"; // show in combobox2
}
```

I want to use the variable `select` to query but it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are `cmb2` and `combobox2` same? You wanna use selected value in `combobox2` as a parameter in your sql query instead? Can you please be more specific? By the way, your `where ROUND=select` won't work if you try to query `select` as a text. You need to use `where ROUND = 'select'` in such a case.

Comment: Yes, the cmb2 is the ComboBox2, but I want to use the selected value in ComboBox1 as a parameter, not in ComboBox2

Comment: `select` is a terrible name for a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your `select` to sql parameter

```
string select = this.cmb1.GetItemText(this.cmb1.SelectedItem);
cm1 = new SqlCommand("select VS from DATABASE where ROUND=@round", con);
cm1.Parameters.Add("@round", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);
cm1.Parameters["@round"].Value = select ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to be careful with simply injecting values into your SQL. If you're going to use ADO like this, I'd recommend parameters.

```
cm1 = new SqlCommand("select VS from DATABASE where ROUND=@ROUND", con);
cm1.Parameters.Add("@ROUND", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cm1.Parameters["@ROUND"].Value = select;
```

- Note - I saw vantian beat me to this answer so I'll try to explain a bit more about why you should use the parameters.

When you use include values posted from a web app (or API or any application where a user can define those values) you can't simply put it inline into your SQL query. A savvy, or a**hole, user can inject their own SQL into their value and your application won't know the difference and run it. With this power, a user can do whatever they want to your data -- such as steal it, or if you're lucky, only delete it to mess with your operations.

The parameters will automatically "cleanse" your input by wrapping the proper quotes and such around it and you will have a far more secure application.

Good luck!