# selected value used as a variable for SQL Query_for Column and for criteria

Tags: c#, sql

Good day.

I am working on a Database app (Windows forms, C#).

My application has an option (i wish) to search by different parameters.

First search parameter/criteria is determined by a button click.
When a button (for example "button1") is clicked, "label4" is assigned a value (different value for a different button; there are 6 buttons). This value is equal to the column name in my Database Table.

Also, after button1 is clicked a combobox ("comboBox1") is populated with data.
[For defining query parameters (from comboBox selection) I used:
[Stackoverflow_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438423/how-to-use-the-selected-value-in-combobox-to-the-sql-query/34438530) and [Stackoverflow_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131690/how-to-write-a-single-sql-query-based-on-combobox-selection).]

So, I tried to use the same principle as I got from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438423/how-to-use-the-selected-value-in-combobox-to-the-sql-query/34438530) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131690/how-to-write-a-single-sql-query-based-on-combobox-selection), but it doesn't seem to work.

The results should be displayed in a "Data Grid View" after "button9 is clicked".
Did I go wrong with "data adapter" and "data set" for the Data Grid View?
If I "hard-code" the column value, it works, so my suspect is "column variable".

Help. Thank you.

**TLDR: how to set variables in SQL string search?**

```
 public void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();

                string column = this.label4.Text;                                       //column is the variable/value which I get when selecting "sort by" button
                string XXX = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);  //XXX is the variable/value which I get when comboBox item is selected
                SqlCommand cmd9 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblTable WHERE @column=@XXX", con);

                cmd9.Parameters.Add("@column", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);
                cmd9.Parameters["@column"].Value = column;

                cmd9.Parameters.Add("@XXX", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);
                cmd9.Parameters["@XXX"].Value = XXX;


                SqlDataAdapter adapter9 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd9);  //to view data in DataGridview I need a "data adapter" and "data set"
                DataSet ds9 = new DataSet();
                adapter9.Fill(ds9, "tblTable");

                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds9.Tables["tblTable"];

                con.Close();

             }


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@column is not a parameter`....

If you want a dynamic query you should use `if-else` statements with concated query string.(List `StringBuilder`)

you need something like:

```
con.Open();

string column = this.label4.Text;                                       
string XXX = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);  
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM tblTable WHERE 1=1");
if(column == "...")
{
    sb .Append(" column=@XXX...");
}
SqlCommand cmd9 = new SqlCommand(sb.ToSTring(), con);

cmd9.Parameters.Add("@XXX", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);
cmd9.Parameters["@XXX"].Value = XXX;

SqlDataAdapter adapter9 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd9);  //to view data in DataGridview I need a "data adapter" and "data set"
DataSet ds9 = new DataSet();
adapter9.Fill(ds9, "tblTable");

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds9.Tables["tblTable"];

con.Close();
```

Also never open and close connections like that, use `Using`

Answer (score 0):

Omriman12 sent me in the right direction.
Here is what works:

```
  public void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();

                string column = this.label4.Text;                                       //column is the variable/value which I get when selecting "sort by" button
                string XXX = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);  //XXX is the variable/value which I get when comboBox item is selected

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                //1
                if (column == "AAA")
                {
                    sb.Append("SELECT * FROM tblTable_values WHERE ").Append(column).Append(" =@XXX");
                }
                //2
                if (column == "BBB")
                {
                    sb.Append("SELECT * FROM tblTable_values WHERE ").Append(column).Append(" =@XXX");
                }
                //3
                if (column == "CCC")
                {
                    sb.Append("SELECT * FROM tblTable_values WHERE ").Append(column).Append(" =@XXX");
                }
                //4
                if (column == "DDD")
                {
                    sb.Append("SELECT * FROM tblTable_values WHERE ").Append(column).Append(" =@XXX");
                }
                //5
                if (column == "EEE")
                {
                    sb.Append("SELECT * FROM tblTable_values WHERE ").Append(column).Append(" =@XXX");
                }
                //6
                if (column == "FFF")
                {
                    sb.Append("SELECT * FROM tblTable_values WHERE ").Append(column).Append(" =@XXX");
                }

                SqlCommand cmd9 = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), con);

                cmd9.Parameters.Add("@XXX", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);
                cmd9.Parameters["@XXX"].Value = XXX;


                SqlDataAdapter adapter9 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd9);  //to view data in DataGridview I need a "data adapter" and "data set"
                DataSet ds9 = new DataSet();
                adapter9.Fill(ds9, "tblTable_values");

                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds9.Tables["tblTable_values"];

                con.Close();

             }
```

yaaaaay!